# Java casting exception FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, exception, android-viewpager

I want to make a custom `fragmentPagerAdapter`. My application crashes and i've got cast exception. This is my code:

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static int[] ICONS = new int[] {
        R.drawable.tab1drawable,
        R.drawable.tab2drawable
};

public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

// ...

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ICONS.length;
}

public int getDrawableId(int position) {
    return ICONS[position];
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
   }
```

And this is the exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.androidsources.welcomescreen/com.androidsources.welcomescreen.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.androidsources.welcomescreen.ViewPagerAdapter cannot be cast to
>   com.androidsources.welcomescreen.HomePagerAdapter

This is the line where crash occurs : `tabs.setViewPager(pager);` and this is the onCreate Method from MainActivity.cs

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);



}`
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: Oncreate MainActivity. This class is used to make a slidingTabLayout with icons (not text). I used that two classes provided by Google (slidingTabLayout and the other one)

Comment: Declare adapter as being of type ViewPagerAdapter , *ViewPagerAdapter adapter*

Comment: ViewpagerAdapter uses text istead of icons , i want to use HomePagerAdapter

Comment: Then instead of *new ViewPagerAdapter()...* use *new HomePagerAdapter()...*

Comment: Can i give you the entire project? :)

Comment: why are you not using the object of your homepageadapter.